# Overlaying a full page with an image

Tags: graphics

Here's what I'm trying to do:  I'm using the document class "report" and letter page size.  I want one particular section to consist of two pages with one flowchart on each page. The flowcharts were made with an external program and saved as PNG's; each image is exactly letter size, and they need to be included at full scale for legibility. Naturally, the first of the two pages is going to have the section number and heading, and both pages will have page number; the flowcharts were designed to avoid the spot where page numbers appear and where the heading will appear to facilitate including them at full scale.

So basically what I want to tell LaTeX is: "make a section with exactly two blank pages, add page numbers, add the section heading on the first of the two pages, then take this image and overlay it on the first page, and then take this other image and overlay it on the second page."

I have no previous experience with any sort of graphics in LaTeX; from what I've been reading it seems like the way to do this is with tikZ and "remember picture" + "overlay", but I haven't been able to find anything written in enough detail to understand what to do.  I also tried the package documentation but I can't figure out nodes for the life of me.

---

This **edit** is a response to Herr K's answer.  The only thing that the given code doesn't address is the issue with the section heading.  Consider the following modification.  I've added `\section{Flowcharts}`, and two lines in the preamble so that each section starts on a new page:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mwe} % this package provides dummy images for illustration purposes

\usepackage{titlesec} %allows for more robust sectioning
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} %starts each section on new page

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Flowcharts}

% 1st image
\clearpage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[]at(current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-letter-numbered}};} % replace example-image* with your own image file

% 2nd image    
\clearpage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[]at(current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-letter-numbered}};} % replace example-image* with your own image file

\end{document}
```

If I include the first `\clearpage`, then the first page of the new section is left blank and the flowcharts are printed on the second and third pages.

If I remove the first `\clearpage`, then the section heading isn't displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is overkill for your use case, but I wrote a package called `pdfoverlay` to easily overlay text on a multi-page PDF file. But it works just as well for single page PDFs and even single page PNGs.

Try something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdfoverlay}

\begin{document}

This is page 1.

\clearpage

\pdfoverlaySetPDF{example-image-letter.pdf}

\chapter{This is a chapter heading}

\clearpage

\pdfoverlaySetPDF{example-image-a4.pdf}
\null % You need some object on the page for LaTeX to output the page.

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool! Did exactly what I wanted - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A TikZ solution as you alluded to:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mwe} % this package provides dummy images for illustration purposes

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

% 1st image
\clearpage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[]at(current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-letter-numbered}};} % replace example-image* with your own image file

% 2nd image    
\clearpage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[]at(current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-letter-numbered}};} % replace example-image* with your own image file

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

The section heading doesn't show because it covered by the image. On way to fix this is to issue the `\section` command after placing the first image, and this requires temporarily suspending the `\sectionbreak` command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mwe} % this package provides dummy images for illustration purposes

\usepackage{titlesec} %allows for more robust sectioning
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage} %starts each section on new page

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

% 1st image
\clearpage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[]at(current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-letter-numbered}};} % replace example-image* with your own image file

{
\renewcommand\sectionbreak{} % temporarily suspends section break
\section{Flowcharts} % add section title after image so that it won't be covered 
}

% 2nd image    
\clearpage
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[]at(current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-letter-numbered}};} % replace example-image* with your own image file

\end{document}
```

Comment: This almost works... I've edited my question to address the remaining issue

Comment: @JosephGranata: I edited my example in response to your comment.